# ios9 : call another framework inside framework project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9.3

I had created my own framework project in Xcode and I want to use method from other framework (example : libA.framework) inside my framework project.

I got crash and show unrecognized error when I run and use method from `libA.framework`, I tried to check method inside `headerA.h` from `libA.framework` but not founded, but it founded in `headerA+Standalone.h`.

What is the difference between `headerA.h` and `headerA+Standalone.h`?
And How to call method inside `headerA+Standalone.h`?

Answer (score 0):

`headerA+Standalone.h` is a [category extension](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories) of `headerA.h` which extends the functionality of `headerA.h`.

Just simply add `#import <FRAMEWORK_NAME/headerA+Standalone.h>`(Where that header resides).  Then you will be able to use the functions inside `headerA+Standalone.h`

Comment: I tried to create category just for testing in my framework project and it worked. but it crashed when my framework call `headerA+Standalone.h` in `libA.framework`. I already import `headerA+Standalone.h` but still same

Comment: Did you make `headerA+Standalone.h` in `libA.framework` as public header ?  If not, do so.  And also add the method on `headerA+Standalone.h`, which you are calling.

Comment: `headerA+Standalone.h` is public header in `libA.framework`, my framework can call method inside `headerA.h` but can't call method inside `headerA+Standalone.h`, I don't know why.

Comment: It's hard to say, what exactly went wrong without checking the code. Share us the code what you are trying.